# What is the command for a struck out exists symbol

Tags: latex

\exists gives you the flipped E, but what is the command for the negated symbol?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The command for the negative existential quantifier is `\nexists`. However, I believe you should ask questions like this on the [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) site of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Note 1: For this to work, you need to add `\usepackage{amssymb}`.  
Note 2: `\not\exists` is an alternative, but `\nexists` looks slightly better.

Answer (score 17):

This is a great site that lets you draw the symbol you want, and it shows a list of possible latex commands. `\nexists` was the first suggestion that popped up! http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html